# Can't Find Landsat7 data

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-7

I am trying to access Landsat7 data for Antarctica, but not getting results

```
    // Boundary of Antarctica
var ant  = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0")
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Antarctica'));

Map.setCenter(-100.00197885595605,-75.65541919954312, 4);

var styleParams = {
  fillColor: 'b5ffb4',
  color: '00909F',
  width: 1.0,
};

var dataset = ant.style(styleParams);
Map.addLayer(ant, {}, 'Antarctica');



var dataset1 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2022-12-31')
    .filterBounds(ant);

print(dataset1)

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}

dataset = dataset1.map(applyScaleFactors);

var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};

// Map.setCenter(-114.2579, 38.9275, 8);

Map.addLayer(dataset1, visualization, 'True Color (321)');
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately sometimes the simplest answer is the right one: there are little to no Landsat 7 images of Antarctica. And if there were, they would require special manipulations to actually be useful. Acquiring imagery from such high/low latitudes is notoriously challenging, and there have been entire projects dedicated to that.

Answer (score 2):

As M. Nicolas noted, there aren't many images, but there were some collection campaigns, just not in the time period you've selected. (see: ee.ImageCollection("USGS/LIMA/SR"))  And all the images that exist are hard to calibrate both geometrically and radiometrically, so they're in Tier 2, not T1.

```
var ant = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
    -180, -60, 0, -60, 180, -60, 180, -88, 0, -88, -180, -88], null, false)

var dataset1 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T2")
    .filterBounds(ant)
print(dataset1.size())   # 84,273
Map.addLayer(dataset1)
```

[image]

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6c200f89b655914c888958eaa56db199